# Getting caret position in IE works in one scenario, doesn't in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` element in HTML markup as below:

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="" />
```

I am changing the characters entered in this input element with Urdu ones (like a mini virtual keyboard), by using jQuery's `keypress`:

```
$("#s").keypress(function(e) {
    var pos = getCaretPos('s');
    // key-mapping logic here
});
```

I also have some buttons that help a user enter their desired Urdu character by clicking on a respective button. Thus:

```
// Process clicks on buttons with class=kb-letter
$(".kb-letter").click(function() {
    var pos = getCaretPos('s');
    // logic for entering Urdu characters in 's' here
});
```

This is the function for getting caret position. It returns the current caret position in `s` and the new character is then inserted at that position:

```
function getCaretPos(areaId) {
    var txtArea = document.getElementById(areaId);
    var pos = 0;
    var br = (document.selection ? "ie" : ((txtArea.selectionStart || txtArea.selectionStart == '0') ? "ff" : false ) );
    if (br == "ie") { 
        txtArea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart ('character', -txtArea.value.length);
        pos = range.text.length;
    }
    else if (br == "ff") {
        pos = txtArea.selectionStart;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Now, the above `getCaretPos()` works fine in Firefox 8 and Chrome 17 for both direct keyboard input in `s` and input using clicking on buttons; but on Internet Explorer 8, it works **only** for direct keyboard input. If I try entering a character using mouse clicks, it gets entered at location 0 because `getCaretPos()` always returns 0 in that case.

I have no idea what is going wrong. Do I need to call `getCaretPos()` in a different manner in response to mouse clicks for IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was using an unordered list with its `<li>`s posing as keyboard buttons. For some reason, IE was having problems with them. I swapped the `<li>`s for `<button>`s and now `getCaretPos()` is working all fine.